# rendering view return java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, null, nullpointerexception

i'm sure what is happening, but i don't know how to fix it.
when

```
<td id="menulateralup" style="width: 280px" >
                    <ui:fragment rendered="true">
                        <p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />
                        <h3>Lista de Insiders</h3>
                        <p:scrollPanel styleClass="bodybarup" mode="native">

                        <p:dataTable id="insiderMenu" value="#{insidersIndexBean.insiderDataModel}" var="insider" selectionMode="single" selection="#{insidersIndexBean.insiderSelected}">

                               <p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="detalle1.show()" update="@form"/>

                                <p:column style="white-space: normal;" >
                                   <h:outputText value="#{insider.nombre} #{insider.app} #{insider.apm}" />
                                   <br/>
                                   <h:outputText value="#{insider.rut}-#{insider.dv}" />
                               </p:column>

                           </p:dataTable>
                        </p:scrollPanel>

                    </ui:fragment>
                </td>
```

when i press over a column's element, show me the dialog below, and it have a datable where values come from seteoModulouno(), but when i try to load the page , it load also values of dialog's datatable and all this values depend of value of column's element that i selected.

```
            <p:dialog header="#{insidersIndexBean.insiderSelected.nombre} : #{insidersIndexBean.insiderSelected.rut} " 
                  widgetVar="detalle1" 
                  modal="true" 
                  draggable="false" 
                  closable="true" 
                  resizable="false" 
                  id="datalle1th1">
        <!--graficos de detalle de in insider-->
        <table>
            <tr><td style="width: 500px">
                    r compras
                    <p:dataTable value="#{insidersIndexBean.seteoModuloUno()}" var="reg" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="100" id="modulo1table1">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                                    Compras (A) de los ultimos 30 dias
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column headerText="Fecha">
                            #{reg.fecha}
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Nemo">
                            #{reg.nemo}
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Unidades">
                            #{reg.unidades}
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Precio ($CLP)">
                            #{reg.precio}
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Total ($CLP)">
                            #{reg.total}
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Bolsa">
                            #{reg.bolsa}
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </td>
```

i want that this dialog won't load values for datatable at init of page, it must to load just when i press over a column's element.

it's clear? D:

i'm using primfaces 3.1, jsf2, springFramework(anotation)

the backbean have a scope session.

Comment: You should include the stacktrace!

Comment: Use `rendered` attibute and check the property which is causing the NPE is not null.